# nbd-client Fsync error

Tags: mount

i try insert USB memory and check the device is "/dev/sdb1"

> root@ubuntu:~# lsblk
>
> NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
>
> sda      8:0    0    64G  0 disk
>
> ├─sda1   8:1    0    63G  0 part /
>
> ├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part
>
> └─sda5   8:5    0  1022M  0 part [SWAP]
>
> sdb      8:16   1   3.8G  0 disk
>
> └─sdb1   8:17   1   3.8G  0 part /media/fd74eeb0-2bf8-49b0-872a-
>   4a283f124c10
>
> sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
>
> sr1     11:1    1  1024M  0 rom

and create network device

> nbd-server -r 2000 /dev/sdb
>
> ** (process:2778): WARNING **: Specifying an export on the command line is deprecated.
>
> ** (process:2778): WARNING **: Please use a configuration file instead.

and client side( same machine )

> nbd-client 172.20.10.3 2000 /dev/nbd0
>
> Negotiation: ..size = 3850MB
>
> bs=1024, sz=4037017600 bytes

and mount nbd device

> mount -o loop /dev/nbd0p1 point/

but mount as follows problem occurs

> root@ubuntu# mount /dev/nbd0p1 point/
>
> mount: block device /dev/nbd0p1 is write-protected, mounting read-only

when i tried modify files in device error occurrs

> vi point/test.c
>
> add lines
>
> and :wq
>
> point/test.c" E212: Can't open file for writing

why ??

i don't understand this

> root@ubuntu:~# dmesg | tail
>
> [  371.280809] loop: Write error at byte offset 3035136, length 4096.
>
> [  371.280810] Buffer I/O error on device loop0, logical block 741
>
> [  371.280812] lost page write due to I/O error on loop0
>
> [  371.280815] loop: Write error at byte offset 4096, length 4096.
>
> [  371.280816] Buffer I/O error on device loop0, logical block 1
>
> [  371.280818] lost page write due to I/O error on loop0
>
> [  389.039901] loop: Write error at byte offset 8396800, length 4096.
>
> [  389.039909] EXT4-fs warning (device loop0): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O
>   error -1 writing to inode 12 (offset 0 size 0 starting block 2050)
>
> [  389.039913] Buffer I/O error on device loop0, logical block 2050
>
> [  391.266099] hrtimer: interrupt took 8643276 ns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

my mistake

nbc-server "-r" option is read-only. ..

remove "-r" and mount -o loop correctly operates